# How can you make an image display in full resolution on a mobile browser?

Tags: html, css

The browser view-port size on a mobile device is often much lower than the screen resolution of that device. For example: on the iPhone X, the screen resolution is 1125 x 2436 whereas the view-port size is 375 x 812.

Given this, how can you make an image display with full resolution on a device such as the iPhone X? If you render an `<img>` whose `src` has a width of `375px`, it will fill the width of the iPhoneX's screen. How can you alter this so that it only fills a third of the screen as per the device's true resolution, and displays in full quality? That is, how can you make the image display in terms of the true screen resolution and not the view-port size.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 33%;
```

or

```
width: 33vh;
```

will have it be one third the width.

Comment: For some mobile devices, the ratio of screen resolution to view-port size is 2:1. For other devices, the ratio is 3:1. How can you ensure the image displays in full resolution on all devices?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it